# Can we make two random variables independent at a low cost?

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, it.information-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two discrete random variables with joint probability mass function $p(x,y)$ such that

$$\|p(x,y)-p(x)p(y)\|_1=\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X},y\in\mathcal{Y}}|p(x,y)-p(x)p(y)|\leq\epsilon$$

Is there any function $f$ such that $X'=f(X)$, $|\mathcal{X}'|‎‎\simeq‎|\mathcal{X}|$ and $p(x',y)=p(x')p(y)$?

Comment: Who is the function $p$ of a single argument? (Not a good idea to use the same letter for two different objects in the same formula.)

Comment: It is the marginal distribution of $p(x,y)$.

Comment: I'm confused: are $p(x,y)$ and $p(x)$ the same functions as $p(x',y)$ and $p(x')$? if they are not, which the title of your posting seems to suggest, you can trivially choose $f(X)=$ constant to make $X'$ independent of $Y$.

Comment: If $X'$ is a non-constant function of $X$ and $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, it's very unlikely that $X'$ and $Y$ will be independent.  If that function is one-to-one, it's impossible.

Comment: $|\mathcal{X}'|‎‎\simeq‎|\mathcal{X}|$ means that $X$ and $X'$ as far as possible have approximately the same alphabet size. Thus, it is unnecessary that $f$ be one-to-one.

Comment: Constant $X'$ or equivalently $|\mathcal{X}'|=1$ is a trivial answer. Can we do better than this?

Comment: Now you're asking whether there are nontrivial events independent of $Y$ in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$.  That may or may not be true.  Generically it is not.  It has very little to do with your inequality.